# Laravel hasmanythrough model places row in wrong parent when primary key number is 'skipped' or when another student is added inbetween the keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

This is about these 4 tables with the following primary keys.

- Courses: CursusNaam varchar
- Exercises: OpdrachtID int
- Exercise progress: OpdrachtVoortgangID int
- Students: LeerlingID int

One course can have many exercises (so exercises has the foreign key CursusNaam).

The progress of the exercises per student is stored in the exercise progress table (so it has the foreign
key OpdrachtID) and of course the exercise progress is linked to a student (so it has the foreign key LeerlingID.

---

What i tried to do is to get and display the latest exercise finished by the student. I did this with an hasManyThrough relation in the course Model.
This works fine when there's only one student in the table exercise progress. However, when i add one more row with a different student in the Exercise progress table, it displays the last OpdrachtVoortgangID from a course to the wrong course!

Exercise progress: This works with one student, it shows right:

[Image of view where it shows right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG8F9.png)

```
INSERT INTO `opdrachtvoortgang` (`OpdrachtVoortgangID`, `LeerlingID`, `OpdrachtID`, `IsKlaar`, `Beoordeling`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, b'1', 'Voldoende'),
(2, 1, 2, b'1', 'Onvoldoende'),
(3, 1, 3, b'1', 'Voldoende'),
(4, 1, 4, b'0', 'onvoldoende'),
(5, 1, 5, b'0', 'Voldoende'),
(6, 1, 6, b'0', 'Voldoende');
```

Exercise progress wrong #1:Adding another student causes OpdrachtVoortgangID:2 (the last one of the course it belongs to) to display to the wrong course:

[Image of view where OpdrachtID 2 moved to wrong course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTmsN.png)

```
INSERT INTO `opdrachtvoortgang` (`OpdrachtVoortgangID`, `LeerlingID`, `OpdrachtID`, `IsKlaar`, `Beoordeling`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, b'1', 'Voldoende'),
-- Different student with id 2 messes it up!
(2, 2, 2, b'1', 'Onvoldoende'),
(3, 1, 2, b'1', 'Onvoldoende'),
(4, 1, 3, b'1', 'Voldoende'),
(5, 1, 4, b'0', 'onvoldoende'),
(6, 1, 5, b'0', 'Voldoende'),
(7, 1, 6, b'0', 'Voldoende');
```

Exercise progress wrong #2: I just found out 'skipping' a primary key number has the same effect as having the progress of another student in between.

```
(1, 1, 1, b'1', 'Voldoende'),
(3, 1, 2, b'1', 'Onvoldoende'),
(4, 1, 3, b'1', 'Onvoldoende'),
(5, 1, 4, b'1', 'Voldoende'),
(6, 1, 5, b'0', 'onvoldoende'),
(7, 1, 6, b'0', 'Voldoende'),
```

Exercise table:

```
INSERT INTO `opdrachten` (`OpdrachtID`, `Opdracht`, `CursusNaam`, `Deadline`) VALUES
(1, '1', 'Laravel-essentials 1', '2021-02-10 13:52:26'),
(2, '2', 'Laravel-essentials 1', '2021-02-20 13:52:26'),
(3, '1', 'ASPAdvanced', NULL),
(4, '2', 'ASPAdvanced', NULL),
(5, '3', 'ASPAdvanced', NULL),
(6, '3B', 'ASPAdvanced', '2021-03-25 23:42:02');
```

Here's the course controller:

```
  $cursussen = Cursus::get();
return view('home')
            ->with(compact('cursussen'))
```

This is how i display it in the view:

```
@foreach ($cursussen as $cursus)   
$cursus->getVoortgang()
@endforeach
```

Here's the Course model:

```
    //get the latest finished exercise by a student
    function getVoortgang()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\OpdrachtVoortgang', 'App\Models\Opdrachten', 'CursusNaam', 'OpdrachtVoortGangID', 'CursusNaam', 'OpdrachtID')
            ->where('LeerlingID', 1) //get progress from student with ID 1
            ->where('IsKlaar', 1) //only exercises that are finished
            ->whereNotNull('IsKlaar' )
            ->orderByDesc('OpdrachtID')
            ->get(); //get instead of first to show that that the progress row got displayed next to the wrong course.
    }
```

Thanks a lot for having a look.
Edit: [This is the output of dd($cursus->getVoortgang())](https://pastebin.com/W4SgP3Nj)

Comment: why are you using with  and compact to gather you can samply do this  `$cursussen = Cursus::get();
return view('home',compact('cursussen'))`

Comment: You have to use the `first()` instate of `get()` to get the latest exercise finished by the student

Answer (score 0):

`get()` returns a collection of objects every time. That collection may have 0 or more objects in it, depending on the results of the query.

`first()` calls `get()` under the hood, but instead of returning the collection of results, it returns the first entry in the collection (if there is one).

Which method you use depends on what you need. Do you need the collection of all the results (use `get()`), or do you just want the first result in the collection (use `first()`)?

I think you want to return the first result in the collection

You have to try this

```
function getVoortgang()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\OpdrachtVoortgang', 'App\Models\Opdrachten', 'CursusNaam', 'OpdrachtVoortGangID', 'CursusNaam', 'OpdrachtID')
            ->where('LeerlingID', 1) //get progress from student with ID 1
            ->where('IsKlaar', 1) //only exercises that are finished
            ->whereNotNull('IsKlaar' )
            ->orderByDesc('OpdrachtID')
            ->first(); //get instead of first to show that that the progress row got displayed next to the wrong course.
    }
```

or

```
function getVoortgang()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\OpdrachtVoortgang', 'App\Models\Opdrachten', 'CursusNaam', 'OpdrachtVoortGangID', 'CursusNaam', 'OpdrachtID')
                ->where('LeerlingID', 1) //get progress from student with ID 1
                ->where('IsKlaar', 1) //only exercises that are finished
                ->whereNotNull('IsKlaar' )
                ->orderByDesc('OpdrachtID')
                ->get()
                ->first(); 
        }
```

Use `get()->first()` it will return only one record, if not find, it will return null.

and you have to order by the id I don't know the id column of your Cursus whatever it is put in in the orderby class

```
$cursussen = Cursus::orderby('id','desc')->get();
return view('home',compact('cursussen'));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The issue is that it should show OpdrachtVoortgangID 2 with first() since that is the last one finished. This works fine when there's only 1 student, however when i add another student in the exercise progress table it disappears (and shows the previous OpdrachtVoortgangID 1). That's why i used get() to see what caused that, it doesn't show  OpdrachtVoortgangID 2 because it somehow moved to the other course.

Comment: did you use `orderBy('OpdrachtID','desc')` instate of `orderByDesc('OpdrachtID')` and can you show me the dd(getVoortgang())`

Comment: Hi i tried that, unfortunately it doesn't change anything. Also with no orderBy the row with OpdrachtID:2 somehow shows next to the wrong course when another student is added.

Comment: I did change it to `$cursussen = Cursus::orderby('CursusNaam','desc')->get();
return view('home',compact('cursussen'));` It does swap the order of the courses. But the problem with OpdrachtID:2 showing in the wrong course row is still the same.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/W4SgP3Nj is what shows when i do `dd($cursus->getVoortgang())`

Answer (score 0):

I've still no idea to what caused this, but by using the 'through' table and adding joins to it solved the weird problem.

```
function getOpdracht()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Opdrachten', 'CursusNaam');
    }
    
 function getOpdrachtLaatstAfgemaakt()
    {
        return $this->getOpdracht()
        ->join('opdrachtvoortgang', 'opdrachten.OpdrachtID', '=', 'opdrachtvoortgang.OpdrachtID')
        ->where('opdrachtvoortgang.IsKlaar', '1')
        ->where('opdrachtvoortgang.LeerlingID', '1')
        ->orderByDesc('opdrachtvoortgangID')
        ->first();
    }
```

Now it no longer shows next to the wrong course in the case there's a progress id number in between missing or when there's another student in between.